# Refresh tableview based on NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` to display data in the `UITableView`. I am inserting a new cell to the table view in `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`, when a new record got added.

What if say 100 records are added. In this case, the delegate will be called 100 times; where inserting of cell happens for 100. How can I improve performance by not inserting cell 100 times?

**NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate** is

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Most demanding work for table tableView is to update the cells that are visible.

So it shouldn't be a concern inserting cells at whether a cell at that indexpath is visible or not.